# Add class to <html> tag at beginning of page in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to add a class to the  tag at the beginning of the HTML rendered in the shiny application.

For example, use this code to generate a basic app:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage()
server <- function(input, output){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you inspect the page, you see the html tag at the beginning as:

```
<html style="overflow: hidden;">
```

I'd like to make it something like this:

```
<html class="myclass" style = "overflow: hidden;">
```

Is there a way to do this without using javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `tags$html` for this. `tags` contains many more other `HTML`tags, you can look for them `?shiny::tags`

```
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(
  tags$html(class="myclass", style = "overflow: hidden;")
)
server <- function(input, output){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

In answer to a comment:

> This doesn't quite do what I want it to. This will add a new html tag inside the page, whereas I want to edit the one that's automatically generated

Are you sure? When I inspect the HTML code I can see that it modified the < html > tag:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I want it to. This will add a new `<html>` tag inside the page, whereas I want to edit the one that's automatically generated.

Comment: I believe, this `tags$html` modifies the automatically generated <html>. I added a screenshoot to my answer

Comment: You're correct. I wasn't fully understanding how RStudio had its page structures, so I got confused in the inspecting part of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `shinyjs` package, it has a function called `addClass()`. It does use javascript under the hood so I'm not sure if this is fine for you or not. It'd be like this:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs())
server <- function(input, output){
  shinyjs::addClass(class = "myclass", selector = "html")
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I didn't want to write my own js to do it, but this is perfect! Thanks!